# How to run some commands before everything else?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am writing a makefile that will download and build all programs that I need on an HPC cluster. Before doing anything else I want it to run this:

```
module add openmpi/1.8.4-gcc
module add slurm
```

These 2 commands modify some environment variables like `MPICC` and `PATH`, so that I can compile mpi programs and schedule them for running. Right now I have them in my `.bashrc`. How do I move them from there to my makefile?

Answer (score 0):

If you run them before running `make`, it will work. If you want those lines to appear in the `Makefile`, you can use `.ONESHELL:`

Otherwise, `make` will spawn one shell process per line, making the `module load` lines useless.

```
$ cat Makefile
CC=g++
SHELL=/bin/bash

.ONESHELL:
all:
    module load R
    R --version
```

While the module is not loaded

```
$ R
-bash: R: command not found
```

running `make` will succeed:

```
$ make
module load R
R --version
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18) -- "World-Famous Astronaut"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
[...]
```

But this will need every rule to include the `module load` commands.